# String Interpolation in Angular 2 with variables that have filters

Tags: angular, lodash

I have a template that allows user to send variables that are in this format

```
{{originalBalance | currency: '£'}}
```

I am parsing the template string with lodash which will parse a variable that is in this format {{client}} but cannot handle the formatting filter and I am struggling to find a package that solves my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add more information. your post doesn't convey enough meaning

Comment: Please put some codes of your ts and html and what are you trying for?